# Upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.04, 20.04

I'm still using Ubuntu 19.04 because it's what was current when I installed the OS but it is no longer supported so I want to upgrade to 20.04 LTS (or even just 19.10).

This should be very simple. There are loads of tutorials on how to upgrade from from `19.10` or `18.04` to `20.04`. But it seems like it's not possible from `19.04`. Could this be true?

If I run `sudo apt upgrade` I get a bunch of 404 errors because the disco archives don't seem to exist anymore. But I ran:

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I tried

```
$ update-manager -c
```

And it told me I was no longer supported and needed updates but when I said "ok" to installing updates it gave me the exact same error.

I'm not sure what to do here. I can't update any more because I can't `apt update`. I guess I could manually set all my apt repos to the Eoan Ermine ones and update again. Is that what I need to do? Where do I set that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). A fresh install of 20.04 is probably the easiest option.

Comment: That was helpful because it let me run `apt update` successfully. But, I still get the exact same error when running `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @karel I'd be happy to upgrade to 19.10 if that's easier. Unfortunately, I'm not able to upgrade at all to either new release

Comment: `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`, `sudo do-release-upgrade`, in this order. Should bring you to 19.10, then the same game again to upgrade to 20.04. I'd prefer a fresh install, it's much quicker.

Comment: FYI: I agree with what mook765 said; though I'd reboot & login to 19.10 & verify everything is good before I bumped to 20.04 (also reboot if required due if upgrades involved kernel or recommend rebooting too in prior steps. Yes it's far quicker to re-install, and skipping is in theory supported; but testing is all on you (for your installed packages unless you have no additional packages as that is not tested except to the next release)

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the answer. I'll probably just reinstall at this point. But I ran those commands in that order and I still get the error about being an unsupported version.